# Check blank/null date in workflow

Tags: 2013, workflow, designer

I have this simple workflow which checks to see if a `Request Date` field is blank to determine whether it goes to `LIST` or `INITIATE` as shown below.

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

- A project is submitted

  - If it doesnt have a request date (is empty), it goes to `2. LIST`
  - If it does have a request date in the request date field, it goes to `3. INITIATE`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Check Three Methods at [Check if Date Field is NULL or Empty in SharePoint Designer Workflow](https://blog.devoworx.net/2015/10/02/check-if-a-date-field-is-null-or-empty-in-sharepoint-designer-workflow/)

Answer (score 7):

I found that a blank date returns 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM instead of blank.  So I just check the date I'm interested in against the item create date.  If it is less than I assume empty.  For my list if currentitem:CompletionDate is less than currentitem:created then...

Comment: To elaborate, the comparison is `If [Project Data: Request Date] is less than or equal to 1/1/0001` then Request Date is empty. (I use 1/1/1900.)

Answer (score -1):

It's a little convoluted, but from memory I think I could only achieve this by setting the 'dateToBeChecked' as variable of type 'String' which then allows you to perform a 'is empty' condition check.