# How to set date/time variable in SharePoint Designer to null/empty?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow, workflow-activity, workflow-variable

How to set date/time variable in SharePoint Designer to null/empty?

I am creating a workflow where I have to set date variable = empty value. But in a lookup, I can't define value=null. Is there any way ?

Comment: Please check here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/61115/check-for-empty-date-in-spd-workflow or here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/176028/check-blank-null-date-in-workflow